# Changing tab opening order in Opera (3 2 1 → 1 2 3)

Tags: opera, browser-tabs

Is it possible to make Opera open tabs in correct order?  E. g. I have a page IndexPage with links Page1, Page2, Page3, and one more tab after IndexPage (say, EndPage):

```
IndexPage | EndPage
```

I open the links in order in which they appear on the page (1, 2, 3), and Opera now has four tabs:

```
IndexPage | Page3 | Page2 | Page1 | EndPage
```

I want it to have

```
IndexPage | Page1 | Page2 | Page3 | EndPage
```

The desired behavior is default in Firefox (at least with TMP) and Chrome.  Firefox+TMP resets the index of where another opened tab will be after user switches to another tab, and Chrome seems to have much more complex rules.

Comment: It's the default for Firefox, even without TMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same need. Here is my solution: (Need 1 extension)

1. Install AutoStack.
2. Uncheck AutoStack preference: 4th, 5th, 6th row.
3. Uncheck Opera - preference - advanced - tabs - "Reuse current tab".

The resulting configuration is:

```
[✓] Auto-stack tabs opened in the foreground
[✓] Auto-stack tabs opened in the background
[✓] Create a new stack if the current tab is not already part of a stack
[  ] Don't create a new stack if the current tab is pinned
[  ] Collapse new stacks
[  ] Open new tab next to active
[  ] Expand the stack when a tab is auto-stacked
[✓] Don't auto-stack these tabs:
```

When you open links in a tab, links will arrange as link1, link2, link3.

---

If you want to close link1, then auto switch to link2; close link2, auto switch to link3, just Opera - prefenrence -advanced -tabs - select "When close a tab, active the next tab".

Comment: Thanks!  That did the job.  I will edit your answer to include the full list of settings.

Comment: Does this still work? New Opera has gone wierd on me

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck "reuse current tab" options, but then tabs will open at the end of the list.

Comment: I want tabs to open at the end of the list of tabs that were opened from a tab.  I will edit the post now.

Comment: Then I don't think so, unless there's an extension that does this.

Comment: @kapsi: I think you meant... uncheck "Open new tab next to active" (rather than "Reuse current tab"), but the result is as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (since you don't specify) that you're talking about opening links in a background tab rather than just navigating to them.

The setting closest to what you're looking for is under `Preferences` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) `>` `Advanced` `>` `Tabs`, it seems you have the option `Open new tab next to active` checked if tabs always open right next to the active tab. It's not checked by default, but if you uncheck it, you still won't get the exact behaviour you get in Firefox, because tabs will then open *at the end* of your tab list.

Personally, I find this behaviour (opening new tabs at the end) more consistent and more intuitive than Firefox's (where, after opening some background links, if you switch tabs and come back to your `IndexPage`, a newly opened background tab will then open *right next to* the `IndexPage` again). But obviously that's a matter of preference.

Comment: I had specified exactly what I want, and opening tabs in the very end of the tabbar is not that.

Comment: @MischaArefiev: 1) Actually, you did _not_ specify whether you're talking about opening tabs in the _background_ (you could've been talking about opening a link in a new tab and going back to the original page to open more links, for instance), hence I stated my assumption for clarification in case it was wrong. 2) Sometimes, there is no perfect answer to a question you ask (in this case, there is no way that I know of to achieve what you're after), so there is no need for a supercilious tone.